# find_package(assimp) could not find assimpTargets.cmake

Tags: cmake

I have successfully build assimp from source, but I run into the following cmake error when calling find_package:

```
CMake Error at libraries/include/assimp/generated/assimpConfig.cmake:27 (include):
  include could not find requested file:
  .../assimp/generated/assimpTargets.cmake

CMake Error at libraries/include/assimp/generated/assimpConfig.cmake:32 (get_property):
  get_property could not find TARGET assimp::assimp.  Perhaps it has not yet
  been created.
```

This fails on `assimpConfig.cmake:27`:

```
include("${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/assimpTargets.cmake")
```

It seems cmake cannot find the file `assimpTargets.cmake`. This file does get generated to the folder `CMakeFiles/Export/.../assimpTargets.cmake`. My CMakeLists.txt fails on the following call:

```
find_package(assimp ${ASSIMP_VER} PATHS "./assimp/generated")
```

What have I may done wrong to fail to generate `assimpTargets.cmake` in the appropriate location?

Comment: You need to **install** assimp. The script `assimpConfig.cmake` is usable only at install location.

Comment: That's correct. `assimpConfig.cmake` of build tree **could** be usable if assimp target was exported in build tree as well (with https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/export.html), but it's missing in CMakeLists of assimp (intentionally or not).